# Cocos2d-x replaceScene causes app crash

Tags: ios, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, assert, cocos2d-x

I'm porting my iOS game from Cocos2d to Cocos2d-x.
I'm not the best with C++ yet so I couldn't debug this on my own !

What I have is a simple scenario of two Scenes, one loads at runtime to show intro, then loads another scene, the first intro scene is loaded by :

```
//Create a scene. it's an autorelease object
CCScene *pScene = landingScene::scene();
// Run intro scene
pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);
```

Now after this loads, everything is okay, till i try to replace that scene by running:

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(mainScene::scene());
```

As soon as I call this , the app asserts and gives the following message:

```
Assertion failed: (index<=arr->num),functionccArrayInsertObjectAtIndex, xxx/libs/cocos2dx/support/data_support/ccCArray.cpp, line 153.
```

I go to the line to check out the line and this is the content:

```
/** Inserts an object at index */
void ccArrayInsertObjectAtIndex(ccArray *arr, CCObject* object, unsigned int index){
    CCAssert(index<=arr->num, "Invalid index. Out of bounds");
    CCAssert(object != NULL, "Invalid parameter!");
...
}
```

This is the content of my Intro (landing) Scene .h file:

```
#ifndef __LANDING_SCENE_H__
#define __LANDING_SCENE_H__

// When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "GameState.h"

class landingScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer {
public:
    landingScene();
    ~landingScene();
    void loadGame();
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
private:
    //The game state Singleton
    GameState *sharedGameState;
};
```

And the .cpp file:

```
#include "landingScene.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#include "mainScene.h"
#include "introScene.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace CocosDenshion;

landingScene::landingScene(){
    setTouchEnabled( true );

    //Load some sprites here, removed it for simplicity

    //This is where the app crashes
    landingScene::loadGame();
}

landingScene::~landingScene(){
}

CCScene* landingScene::scene(){
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    CCLayer *layer = new landingScene();
    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

void landingScene::loadGame(){
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(mainScene::scene());
}
```

And this is the content of my Main scene that I'm trying to show:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_SCENE_H_
#define _MAIN_SCENE_H_

//When you import this file, you import all the cocos2d classes
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "GameState.h"

class mainScene : public cocos2d::CCLayer {
public:
    ~mainScene();
    mainScene();
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
private:
    GameState *sharedGameState;
};
#endif // _MAIN_SCENE_H_
```

And the .cpp file:

```
#include "mainScene.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace CocosDenshion;

mainScene::mainScene(){
}

mainScene::~mainScene(){
}

CCScene* mainScene::scene(){
    // 'Scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = new CCScene();

    // Add layer as a child to scene
    CCLayer* layer = new mainScene();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    layer->release();

    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is you replaced the scene even before your first scene is finished creating. Try to call the replace function in onEnter() or onTransitionDidfFinished()

Comment: My pleasure, time to back home~ just gonna finish today's work in 10 min~